# How to add JavaScript inline in WordPress using wp_add_inline_script?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add inline JavaScript to my WordPress frontend using `wp_add_inline_script`.

- According to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) it should work (as long as I add a script to the queue, which is true in my case)!

  > Code will only be added if the script in already in the queue.
- An equivalent snippet for styles instead of scripts works as expected (see my second snippet below)!

My current snippet which doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_register_script( 'test-handle', '', array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test-handle' ) );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'test-handle', 'does not work' )
} );
```

The following snippet works as aspected but is for styles instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_register_style( 'test-handle', '', array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-handle' ) );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'test-handle', 'works. is what I want.' )
} );
```

---

I'd like to use `wp_add_inline_script` because of its advantages (eg synchronize order, etc)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the function `wp_add_inline_script` was already implemented it didn't work in WordPress version 4.x. Since WordPress version 5.x its working just as expected.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_register_script( 'test-handle', '', array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test-handle' ) );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'test-handle', 'does work since WP 5.x' )
} );
```